# Excel: Creating a formula that skips weekends

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I created a basic excel formula that checks to see if the date entered is 15 days before the current date. The formula relies on a simple formula:

```
=DATE(YEAR(H4),MONTH(H4),DAY(H4)+15)
```

What I have been asked to do is create a formula that checks to see if 15 **working days** have passed (so weekends do not count).

Is there an easy formula I could used that does not require creating a macro?

Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WORKDAY() function from Excel seems to do exactly what you need.
You can specify the start date, the 15 workdays that should pass, and give it a list of state holidays etc (i.e. days that do not count as workdays). Weekends are automatically excluded.

Look at the [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/workday-function-f764a5b7-05fc-4494-9486-60d494efbf33) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

This formula will exactly check whether the Entered Date is 15 days before to the Current Date, then get the Workday's Date, excluding Weekends.

[image]

```
=IF(TODAY()-15=B2,WORKDAY(B2,15,E$2:E$5),WORKDAY(B2,15))
```

Comment: Thanks for the extension to the question, this may help others with a similar question. I've set my excel sheet to display "Yes" or "No" depending on whether it is within 15 days or not but this may help others.

Comment: In this case replace WORKDAY(B2,15,E$2:E$5 with Yes and other with No. So simple,, in fact my solution is based on your original issue, "What I have been asked to do is create a formula that checks to see if 15 working days have passed (so weekends do not count)."